# Setting target platform on the command line in vc++ 2010

Tags: visual-c++

I've been Googling around but without any luck. Can anyone tell me how to set the target platform to x86 only rather than any CPU, on the command line for Vc++ 2010? I am using Code::Blocks and it doesn't present this option in the gui from what I can see because it doesn't seem to know about vc++ 2010. The highest it goes is 2008, at least in my version.